# mysql select more than one result using group by

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

A table 'employees' with

```
id integer, 
name string, 
office integer, 
income decimal
```

How can i select in one query the 3 best income for each office (if possible) ?

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM employees 
GROUP BY office 
ORDER BY income DESC
```

will return only one guy/office

Comment: Consider providing sample data set with your expected result set

Comment: The query you posted shouldn't work. You group by a column and then select other data. That is completely illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a way to do this but by a little workaround you'll get what you want, check this  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de4de1/10) for the tested query.

```
select * from employees as e1 having 4>=(select count(*) from employees as e2 where e1.income<e2.income);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get 3 highest incomes per office you can use rank query with user defined variables,unfortunately in other RDBMS it easier to achieve this kind of results by using window functions by Mysql don't have these functions available,Below query will give you the 3 employees with highest income per office

```
SELECT t.id,t.name
FROM (
SELECT *,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = office THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END row_num,
@g:= office
FROM employees 
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @g:=NULL,@r:=0) a
ORDER BY office,income DESC 
) t 
WHERE t.row_num <=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the highest income for each office:

```
SELECT office, max(income)
FROM employees 
GROUP BY office
```

Get the employees with these incomes:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.office
FROM employees as e
INNER JOIN (SELECT office, max(income) as income FROM employees GROUP BY office) as mx ON e.office = mx.office and e.income = mx.income
```

**Edit:**

I copied the SQLFiddle of Ajeesh to test the queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de4de1/14/0

Comment: only returns one best income/office.

Comment: Could it be that you edited your original question? I could swear that there was no "3 best income" in the beginning.